# How can I output multiple results from an array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have this array of objects, that initially only had **name** and **unit** fields. I recently added a **unitConv** field of array type.

I used to output an array of strings with the name and unit from every object.

```
const ingredients = [
  {name: 'wine', unit: 'ml', unitConv: []},
  {name: 'salt', unit: 'gr', unitConv: [{unitMeasure: { name: 'spoon'}}, {unitMeasure: { name: 'tea-spoon'}}]},
  {name: 'onion', unit: 'piece', unitConv: []},
]

const response = ingredients.map(ing => `${ing.name} [${ing.unit}]`)
```

And this is the response:

```
["wine [ml]", "salt [gr]", "onion [piece]"]
```

Now that I added `unitConv`, I want to see if any `unitConv` are available in the object, and pass those too, as options, like this:

```
["wine [ml]", "salt [gr]", "onion [piece]", "salt[spoon]", "salt[tea-spoon]"]
```

And I want to keep the initial value of salt too, the one the uses the ***'gr'*** as a unit. So for salt, because I have one **unit** and two **unitConv**, I want to output it three times, with each of this options.
If one of the objects doesn't have unitConv, the unitConv fields will appear as an empty array, like in the example above.

Comment: Does my answer work for you?

Comment: Yes it does, thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`Array#flatMap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap) to create the second array to concatenate with the first.

```js
const ingredients = [
  {name: 'wine', unit: 'ml', unitConv: []},
  {name: 'salt', unit: 'gr', unitConv: [{unitMeasure: { name: 'spoon'}}, {unitMeasure: { name: 'tea-spoon'}}]},
  {name: 'onion', unit: 'piece', unitConv: []},
]

const response = ingredients.map(ing => `${ing.name} [${ing.unit}]`)
     .concat(ingredients.flatMap(({name, unitConv})=>
         unitConv.map(x => `${name} [${x.unitMeasure.name}]`)));
console.log(response);
```

Answer (score 0):

a simple array reduce method:

```js
const ingredients = 
        [ { name: 'wine', unit: 'ml', unitConv: [] } 
        , { name: 'salt', unit: 'gr', unitConv: 
              [ { unitMeasure: { name: 'spoon'     } } 
              , { unitMeasure: { name: 'tea-spoon' } } 
              ] 
          } 
        , { name: 'onion', unit: 'piece', unitConv: [] } 
        ] 

const resp2 = ingredients.reduce((resp,{name,unit,unitConv}) =>
        {
        resp.push( `${name} [${unit}]` )
        unitConv.forEach(({unitMeasure}) =>
          resp.push(`${name} [${unitMeasure.name}]`))
        return resp
        },[])

console.log( resp2 )
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper{max-height:100% !important;top: 0;}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use flatMap and inside its callback function check for unitConv array lentgh, if it's true then you can use a map for that. here is the demo:

```js
const ingredients = [{
    name: 'wine',
    unit: 'ml',
    unitConv: []
  },
  {
    name: 'salt',
    unit: 'gr',
    unitConv: [{
      unitMeasure: {
        name: 'spoon'
      }
    }, {
      unitMeasure: {
        name: 'tea-spoon'
      }
    }]
  },
  {
    name: 'onion',
    unit: 'piece',
    unitConv: []
  },
]

function strFormat(name, unit) {
  return `${name} [${unit}]`;
}

const result = ingredients.flatMap((ing) => {
  if (ing.unitConv.length) {
    const ingAllUnits = ing.unitConv.map((unit) => strFormat(ing.name, unit.unitMeasure.name));
    ingAllUnits.push(strFormat(ing.name, ing.unit));
    return ingAllUnits;
  } else return strFormat(ing.name, ing.unit);
});

console.log(result);
```